# error in bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I have input files of this format

```
real 0.00  
user 0.00  
sys 0.00  
real 0.00  
user 0.00  
sys 0.00  
real 0.00  
user 0.00  
sys 0.00
```

I'm writing a bash script to get the average of the 'real' values. This is the script I've written

```
#! /bin/sh

# FILES=/home/myfiles

 for f in $FILES
 do
        echo " Processing $f file.."
        sum=0;
        grep real $f  | while read LINE; do
                value=$(sed "s/[^0-9]//g")
                #value=`awk "^[0-9]"`
                echo $value
                $sum+=$value
        done
        #average=$sum/10;
        #echo $average
 done
```

But I'm getting an error in this stmt

```
$sum+=$value
```

Any solutions plz ?

Comment: Are you sure, time will always display two decimal places?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
sum+=$value
```

Otherwise you'd be saying "0+=$value"

Also, you can do:

```
grep real $f  | while read LINE value; do
```

That'll avoid the need to sed/awk.

Comment: thanks, I tried this its wrking, But the value of sum is being appended like a string instead of adding like an integer sum: 0.000.000.000.000.000.000.00

Comment: @Erik, in the end, awk or bc is still needed to do decimal calculations. In the end, its still better to use just `awk` to do the average.

Comment: bash will work fine, you just need to strip the decimal point (and add it back to your result) ... once you are dealing with just ints - try to perform the operation with `let sum+=value` or `((sum+=value))`

Comment: @jessi ... did you get the part about removing the decimal point?

Comment: @jessi - I think I know why it didnt work ... please see full answer below

Answer (score 2):

bash does not support floating point arithmetic. It only supports integer. If you don't care how to get the result, awk is better equipped for this:

```
awk '/real/ {sum += $2} END {print sum}' files*
```

The /real/ says, "look for those lines with the word real", then {sum += $2} means add the second field to sum. By default, a variable like sum will starts as empty or zero depends on context. Finally, the END pattern says, "after processing all the files, print the sum."

Answer (score 2):

Its better to use `awk` or some programming language that does file processing as well as floating maths all in one. Bash does not support floating point maths. The problem with your script is , you call external `sed` command for every "real" lines you find. This is a performance hit.

```
awk '/real/{s+=$2;c++}END{print "average is: " s/c}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick try, based on our discussion above.
I tried not to change your script too much
here is a summary

- Values are dumped into an array (the pipes you had cause the math to occur at a subshell, results would not make it up to the 'main' shell
- Added more processing in the sed expression to strip leading zeros (but make sure there is at least one digit)
- I didnt follow why to calculate average you divided by 10, so I use the actual count of items in the array
- finally, assuming you want the average in the same unit of meeasurement as the input - I am printing with printf the result of dividing by 100.

-

```
#! /bin/sh

# FILES=/home/myfiles
FILES=a
 for f in $FILES
 do
        echo " Processing $f file.."
        values=($(grep real ${f} | sed -e "s/[^0-9]//g" -e "s/^0*//" -e "s/^$/0/"))
        sum=0;
        for value in ${values[@]}; do
          echo $value
          ((sum+=value))
        done
        average=$((sum/${#values[@]}));
        printf "AVG: %d.%02d\n" $((average/100)) $((average%100))
 done
```

Comment: @jessi  You are welcome! (please remember to accept an answer, using the check-mark under the number on the left)